# upload data and images to server and update timestamp only when everything is uploaded

Tags: android

I have created an app and sorry for the noob question.I am trying to upload data and images from my phone and sqlite to my server via php.

I would like to update the timestamp only after both data and images are done uploading and even if it stops at 90% it should not update the timestamp.How can I achieve it?

I have tried upadating with async (2 parallel async for 2 different php)But I the timestamp is updated only when either of the process is completed .As I dont know how much time its going to take my upload time is not perfect all the time.How can I solve this problem?

```
  Summary:
    1.Data 
    2.Images

    2 phps triggered from 2 different/parallel async

Upload both and update timestamp in sqlite ,if it stops in-between dont update timestamp?
```

I really appreciate any help.I am stuck here from 2 weeks now and I  dont know how to solve it.

Comment: The timestamp of what?

Comment: Timestamp when it was last uploaded both data and images

Comment: Files have timestamps. What do you want to stamp where?

Comment: Basically I am uploading data and images and recording the time when it was last updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this has to do with Android. 
However, if you're uploading your data from an Android client, and you know how much data and how many images need to be uploaded, you can just use a CountDownLatch. 
That is, create a separate thread, to update the timestamp, locked by a CountDownLatch variable, that is shared by all uploading threads. After each thread finishes its work, just do a countdown on the latch. Hence, when the latch reaches 0, it will execute your timestamp update.

Comment: Can you post the link for the same.

Comment: You have rather a specific case, so I'm guessing you should look for tutorial of how you can work with a CountDownLatch. Start from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Answer (score 0):

Keep two `lastuploadedtime`s in Shared preferences. One for de data task and one for the images task. Let every task in onPostExecute() update its lastuploaded time when it is completely done and there were no errors.